# Neither BindingResult nor plain target from Thymeleaf despite bound to model

Tags: java, spring, forms, thymeleaf

I am getting the following error from using Thymeleaf:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contactForm' available as the request attribute
```

Evaluating this expression:

```
#fields.hasErrors('actualName') ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" (template: "fragments/general.html
```

The error message seems improper since the code does actually bind the contact form:

```
  @GetMapping(value = {"/", "/home"})
  public String main(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Home Page");
    model.addAttribute("contactForm", new ContactForm());
    setupVisitor(request, model);
    return "index";
  }
```

Two strange things:

1. It only happens in production when the application (executable Jar) is **behind Apache2** (redirecting port 8080 to port 80). By the way, this complicates things because debugging in production is difficult.
2. Despite the error, the application works (but writes lot of text into the log file!)

Does anybody have a suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Here is the log:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1415) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1159) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
...
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('actualName') ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" (template: "fragments/general.html" - line 229, col 12)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('actualName') ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control'" (template: "fragments/general.html" - line 229, col 12)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contactForm' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar!/:6.0.8]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:232) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.checkErrors(FieldUtils.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.hasErrors(FieldUtils.java:71) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.expression.Fields.hasErrors(Fields.java:58) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```